# Parse server is shutting down or we wont be able to access its framework?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-framework

Can anyone please confirm me that whether only Parse hosted server is shutting down or everything will be shutdown? I mean can we access MongoDB using parse framework after 30 Jan 2017?

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Only parse.com will be shutting down (This includes access to data that sits on parse.com) .Parse-server is open source and will continue as normal!  Just ensure that you have moved your data over to your db (mongo) installation .